# Magento2: How to uncheck "Use Default Value" for description

Tags: magento2

I need to uncheck for all products description in one time "Use Default Value" for specific store.

In `products --> Catalog` I can switch store view example from default store view to English and then edit product and then in description uncheck "Use Default Value".

In single product I can switch store view:
[image]

and then uncheck:
[image]

But for above 11k products take more time. Any one know how to uncheck for all products description in one time?

Answer (score 0):

This is dangerous, it's direct database manipulation and you should create a backup before you try this, but I think what you want to do is:

```
INSERT INTO `{MY DATABASE NAME}`.`catalog_product_entity_text` (`attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES ('76', '{store ID you want to change it in}', '{Product entity id}', '<p>Description you want to show for this product in this scope view</p>'); //this will untick short description

//Attribute ID 76 FOR catalog_product_entity_text is short description, //Attribute ID 75 FOR catalog_product_entity_text is regular description,
```

You're going to want to loop through those 11k entity ids, good luck, hope this helped